# Can a Windows service run configured with one user account but when logged in with different accounts?

Tags: windows, windows-services

Suppose a Windows service is configured with a user account, name it "user1". Is it necessary that to run that service we have to log in that system with the same user i.e. user1 which has been configured? If I logging in with the user2 with administrative privilege will it cause any problem in starting the service?

Please leave comment if I am not clear in asking the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can run any service with any user. The user account that is used to run a service is completely independent on the user that is logged in (there doesn't even need to be a user logged in at all). Just make sure you provide the correct credentials (name and password) in the service properties for the user which should be running the service.